# C# Disable Form

Tags: c#, forms

I've created a menu form with two checkboxes. When I select one of them, I want to disable another form. I tried to write this code:

```
void CheckBox1CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true){
            checkBox1.Checked=true;
            checkBox2.Checked=false;

            classificheForm cf=new classificheForm();
            cf.Enabled=false;

            classificheJunioresForm cjf=new classificheJunioresForm();
            cjf.Enabled=false;
        }
    }
```

but doesn't work, indeed forms aren't disable. How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to use the instance of the form you want to disable, you are creating a new form and trying to disable it

Comment: is another form already shown? show that part of your code where you show an instance of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `Form` and immediately disabling it:

```
classificheForm cf=new classificheForm();
cf.Enabled=false;
```

Instead you should use the reference to the `Form` you want to disable. For example if in the constructor you create the form:

```
classificheForm cf;

public SomeClassConstructor()
{
    cf=new classificheForm();
}
```

Then in your event you would just do:

```
cf.Enabled=false;
```

Note that you can also hide and show forms like:

```
cf.Hide();
cf.Show();
```

---

Note that needing to disable a `Form` sounds like an XY problem. If you don't need the form anymore close it or hide it. Also only use `Form`s when they are needed etc...

If you need to disable a main `Form` whilst you use a dialog `form` it is best to call

```
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

as this will block users being able to interact with the main `Form` until they have closed the dialog one.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong in another part of the code. In my menu I have a button to redirect me in this form, but If I select the checkbox I want that form will not show. I need to modify also the button?

Answer (score -1):

You can easily hide a Form

```
classificheForm cf=new classificheForm();
cf.Show();

classificheJunioresForm cjf=new classificheJunioresForm();
cjf.Hide();
```

Or what do you mean with "disable"?